# I am not able to change the font size of the terminal text by using a command in the terminal itself

Tags: jquery-terminal

I have a terminal using jQuery.Terminal and I want to change the font size of the font of the text in the terminal using a command. But no matter what it just doesn't allow to do.

Also, I want to echo a part of the same string using some fontcolor and the other part using some other fontcolor, is that possible?

```
fontsize: function(size) {      
                $('.terminal').css({"--size":size});
            }
```

I tried the above and initialized the terminal using this

```
$('body').terminal({
```

jQuery Version : 3.3.1

Comment: What version of jQuery you're using? older versions don't support CSS variables.

Comment: I am using 3.3.1 version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using 3.3.1 version of jQuery, when changed to 3.6.4, it worked fine. Thanks jcubic